# Application of law of large numbers for triangular arrays

Tags: probability, asymptotics, random, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $\{\xi_j\}_{j=1}^J$.

Consider a random variable $X$ with support $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the map $f: \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^J$. Let $f_j(X)$ be the $j$-th element of the $J\times 1$ random vector $f(X)$.

Assume that $E(\xi_j| X)=0$ $\forall j=1,...,J$.

I want to show that
$$
\frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J f_j(X) \xi_j\rightarrow_p0 \text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$} 
$$

---

The book I'm reading claims that this holds because:

- The random variables in the sequence $\{f_j(X) \xi_j\}_{j=1}^J$ are i.i.d. conditional on $(f_j(X) \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J)$.
- Hence, under the **law of large numbers for triangular arrays**, $
  \frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J f_j(X) \xi_j\rightarrow_p0$ as $J\rightarrow \infty$

---

I'm struggling to understand this proof.

The law of large number for triangular arrays states:
Consider the triangular sequence $\{(Y_{J,j})_{j=1}^J\}_{J \in \mathbb{N}}$. Assume $Y_{J,1},\ldots,Y_{J,J}$ are i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu_J$. Then, under some conditions [?], it holds that 
$$
{1 \over J}\sum_{j=1}^J Y_{J,j}-\mu_J \to_p 0 \text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$}  $$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317869/strong-law-of-large-number-for-triangular-arrays) for example).

But what is $ Y_{J,j}$ in my example? Could you help me to clarify?

Comment: Does the book give any conditions that $f$ has to satisfy? After all, if $f_j(x)=2^jx$ then  $\frac{1}J\sum_{j=1}^Jf_j(X)\eta_j$ might not converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation:

First of all, $f$ should really be $f^J$ since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^J$ so different $J$'s $\implies$ different $f$'s.

Then the thing you want to prove becomes (edit in red):

$$\frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J f^\color{red}{J}_j(X) \xi_j\rightarrow_p0 \text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$}$$

Then comparing to your theorem for triangular array, we identify $Y_{J,j} \equiv f^J_j(X) \xi_j$, and note that:

$$\mu_J = E[Y_{J,j}] = E[f^J_j(X) \xi_j] = E_X [ E_\xi [\xi_j | f^J_j(X)]] = E_X [ 0] = 0$$

---

However, as pointed out by the comment of @AngelaRichardson, you might be missing some condition on $f$ (and/or on $Y$).  E.g. consider:

$$f^J_j(X) = \begin{cases}
JX, & j = J\\
0, & j < J
\end{cases}
$$

Then:

$$\frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J f^J_j(X) \xi_j = \frac{1}{J} (JX) \xi_j = X \xi_j \not\to_p 0$$

Even if you additionally impose the condition that $f_j^J = f_j^K$ for all $j,J,K$ in range, this would rule out the above example but the example by Angela that $f_j(X) = 2^j X$ is still likely to lead to $\not\to_p 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some sufficient conditions for the triangular law of large numbers to hold (e.g., finiteness and existence of some moments, etc....)? Maybe the book considers them implicit. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it is still unclear to me how we get i.i.d.ness of $\{f_j^J(X)\xi_j\}_{j=1}^J$ from the assumptions.

Comment: I personally have not heard of the triangular law until this post.  I was simply trying to fit the first part of what you said into the second part of what you said.  :)  However, you have a good point...  I'd think $\{f^J_j(X) \xi_j\}_{j=1}^J$ are _NOT_ i.i.d. because the components $f_j$ can certainly correlate.  Even your book only claimed they are i.i.d. when conditioned on ${f^J_j(X)}_{j=1}^J$, but even that seems false: they might be _independent_ when conditioned, but how can they be _identically distributed_?  The $\xi$'s are i.d. but when scaled by $f_j$ they shouldn't be i.d.